# Elisp: How to push-back to a list

Tags: lisp, elisp

Is there a way to push-back to a list in elisp?

The closest thing I found was

```
(add-to-list 'myList myValue t) ;; t tells it to put to back of the list
```

The problem, however, is that add-to-list enforces uniqueness. The other alternative is `(push 'myList myVal)` but that can only push to the front of a list. I tried using `(cons myList myVal)` but IIRC that returns something other than a list.

The only thing that has worked is

```
(setq myList (append myList (list myVal)))
```

but that syntax is hideous and feels like a lot of extra work to do something simple.

Is there a faster way to push to the back of a list. It's clearly possible as seen in `(add-to-list)`, but is there a way to do it without enforcing uniqueness?

In other words, a good old push-back function like with C++ and the `<List>` class

Comment: As a follow-up question, why is elisp so sparse. I feel like it just has the bare minimum necessary to work. Is there some sort of philosophy behind this?

Comment: it is a Lisp, e.g. an extensible language. You can always write a macro if something annoys you and change the behavior.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Lisp lists vs "lists" in other languages

Lisp lists are chains of cons cells ("linked lists"), not specialized sequential containers like in C, and not a weird blend of lists and vectors like in Perl and Python.

This beautiful approach allows the same methodology to be applied to **code** and **data**, creating a *programmable programming language*.

The reasons Lisp does not have a "push-back" function are that

- it does not need it :-)
- it is not very well defined

## No need

Adding to the end is linear in the length of the list, so, for
accumulation, the standard pattern is to combine
[`push`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_push.htm) while iterating and
[`nreverse`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_revers.htm) when done.

## Not well defined

There is a reason why `add-to-list` takes a `symbol` as the argument (which makes it useless for programming).

What happens when you are adding to an empty list?
You need to modify the *place* where the list is stored.

What happens when the list shares structure with another object?
If you use

```
(setq my-list (nconc my-list (list new-value)))
```

all the other objects are modified too.

If you write, like you suggested,

```
(setq my-list (append my-list (list new-value)))
```

you will be allocating `(length my-list)` cells on each addition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(defun prueba ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((mylist '(1 2 3)))
    (message "mylist -> %s" mylist)
    (add-to-list 'mylist 1 t)
    (message "mylist -> %s" mylist)
    (setq mylist '(1 2 3))
    (add-to-list 'mylist 1 t '(lambda (a1 a2) nil))
    (message "mylist -> %s" mylist)
    ))
```

adding a compare function that always returns nil as the fourth argument to `add-to-list`  allows you
to add duplicates.